# Redundant id for table with unique foreign key?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I'm learning how to use Hibernate and I have a question relating to ids for tables that have a one-to-one relationship.

There are two tables, `Employee` and `Account`, that have a one-to-one relationship. The primary key for an `Employee` is an employee id. I want to use this id for an `Account` and I understand that it can therefore be defined as a foreign key in the `Account` table.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee
{
    @Id
    private int employeeId;
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Account
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int tempId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employeeId", referencedColumnName = "employeeId", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="FK_Account_Employee"))
    private Employee employee;
}
```

Note that `Account` has an additional id field that I don't need as the employee id foreign key is unique. If I remove `tempId` then I get an exception at runtime.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.company.entity.Account
```

Is it possible to declare `Account` without this additional id?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation. It is used for keeping a single unique key on one-to-one and many-to-one relationships which works the same as primary and foreign-key. Find the documentation below:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_Relationships